# How do I join tables where a column has exactly all values that I want?

Tags: sql

I have a table A with column B_ID refering to B_ID in table B
Table B has B_ID as primary key and C_ID refering to C_ID in table C

I want to select from A join B on A_ID where B.C_ID = 5 AND B.C_ID = 4

for example when I do this:

```
select from A join B on B.A_ID = A.A_ID
```

If the result is :

```
A_ID  |  B_ID  |  C_ID
 1    |   1    |   4
 1    |   2    |   5
```

Then I want the query to return both rows
But if the result is :

```
A_ID  |  B_ID  |  C_ID
 1    |   1    |   4
```

I want the query to return 0 rows.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If `A_ID` is the primary key in `A`. How can you have two records with `A_ID=1` and different `B_ID`s if the `A` and `B` are joined through `B_ID`. Are you sure that the join shouldn't be `A INNER JOIN B ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID`?

Comment: yes the join is on A_ID actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    whatever
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE
    B.C_ID IN (4, 5)
```

or

```
SELECT
    whatever
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE
    B.C_ID = 4 OR B.C_ID = 5
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want only matching pairs

```
SELECT
    whatever
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE
    A.A_ID IN (SELECT A_ID
               FROM B
               WHERE C_ID IN (4, 5)
               GROUP BY A_ID
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) AND
    B.C_ID IN (4, 5)
```

The sub-select groups by `A_ID` and counts the records. The HAVING clause works like the WHERE clause but is executed after grouping. So the inner select returns only `A_ID`s corresponding to (4, 5)-pairs of `C_ID`. The whole query always returns an even number of records like

```
A_ID  |  B_ID  |  C_ID
 1    |   1    |   4
 1    |   2    |   5
 2    |   3    |   4
 2    |   4    |   5
```

---

**EDIT**

If you only want A_IDs where not only C_IDs 4 and 5 are present but where no further C_IDs exist then change the query to

```
SELECT B.*
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE B.C_ID IN (4, 5) AND
      A.A_ID IN (SELECT A_ID
                 FROM B
                 GROUP BY A_ID
                 HAVING MIN(C_ID)=4 AND MAX(C_ID)=5 AND COUNT(*)=2)
```

If the two numbers (4 and 5 in this example) are always contiguous, you can drop the `COUNT(*)=2` part.

(Note: accoring to one of your comments the join is on the `A_ID` column. I changed that in all my examples.)

**UPDATE by Robin**

Thanks, with your help I came up with this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A a
    INNER JOIN B
        ON a.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B b WHERE b.A_ID = a.A_ID and C_ID IN (4, 5)) =
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A aa INNER JOIN B b ON aa.A_ID = b.A_ID WHERE b.A_ID = a.A_ID)
```

Comment: IN and OR will return the row if C_ID = 4 or C_ID = 5. I want to get the values only if the pairs (A_ID, C_ID): (1, 4) and (1, 5) both exist. If there is only the (1, 5) pair, I want no result

Comment: I think the OP wants to return rows only when both rows exist

Comment: And what if you have 3, 4 or more rows. Should it always return pairs?

Comment: if i am only looking for C_ID = 4 and C_ID = 5, no

Comment: Yes OK, but A_ID could be 2, 3, 4, not just 1.

Comment: Ok, and what if we change (4, 5) to (4) and COUNT(*) = 1, if there are more pairs like (1,4) and (1,5) I don't want them. But if there's (2, 4) i want it to appear

Comment: My updated query will return all the rows with C_ID IN (4, 5) where both 4 and 5 exist for distinct A_IDs.

Comment: Yes but if another c_id (other than 4,5) exists for a given a_id, it will also return the rows, which i don't want. It is close though, i tried doing    HAVING COUNT(*) = (select count(*) from A inner join B on A.B_ID = B.B_ID) but still doesn't work

Comment: Change the subselect to `(SELECT A.A_ID
                   FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.B_ID = B.B_ID
                   GROUP BY A.A_ID
                   HAVING MIN(B.C_ID)=4 AND MAX(B.C_ID)=5)`

Comment: This (see last comment) works only because there cannot be a record between 4 and 5. If you had two non-contiguous numbers you would have to add a `AND COUNT(*)=2`.

Comment: the thing is, i can choose 4, 5, 6 or 1, 3, 5. I think trying to put another sub request instead of = 2 is the solution

Comment: If will only work with two numbers at the same time, beacuse MIN and MAX can only return two distinct numbers.

Comment: Your update to my comment will discard results with a greater number of rows than 2 but not records with only one row.

Comment: It should be `SELECT
    *
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.A_ID = A.A_ID AND C_ID IN (4, 5)) = 2 AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.A_ID = A.A_ID) = 2`. This will also work for three numbers like (4, 5, 7). The table A is actually not necessary in the sub-selects. I removed it from my examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.B_ID = B.B_ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE C_ID = 4)
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE C_ID = 5)
```

Would work - there's probably a better way though, let me think...

(of course the above assumes you only have 1/2 rows in the table)

Or

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.B_ID = B.B_ID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE C_ID IN (4,5)) > 1
```

Play around with it!

Comment: That should work, but if I was looking for the only pair (1, 4) and both (1, 4) and (1, 5) exist, I don't want any results.

Comment: No doesn't work, since B could have records with C_ID = 4 or 5 in rows that are not joined to A and would returns rows with other C_IDs as well beacuse `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE C_ID = 4)` only says that a C_ID = 4 exists somewhere in the table B.

Comment: can i check that only c_id = 4 and no other rows with the same a_id has another c_id ?

Comment: Your answer also helped me out

Answer (score 0):

```
 select B.* from
    A join B on B.B_ID = A.B_ID, 
    (
    select 1 as test from 
    (
    select distinct c_Id from 
    A join B on B.B_ID = A.B_ID
    where c_Id in (4,5)
    ) tmp
    having COUNT(*) = 2
    ) tmp2
    where tmp2.test = 1
```

Comment: HAVING without GROUP BY? Won't that return the whole table B if the conditions is met?

Comment: it is possible to use HAVING without GROUP BY, but in that case it is not possible to select any column without aggregation function